# Excel Export as Unicode Pipe Delimited

Tags: excel, vba

Right now I'm trying to save an excel sheet with VBA as a pipe delimited unicode file with a .txt extension.

I've figured out how to save it as unicode with code as follows

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=FileName, _
FileFormat:=xlUnicodeText
```

But this will save it as tab delimited.  I can't seem to find an option with MSDN, as their page on [FileFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.xlfileformat.aspx) isn't very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

As saving as a .csv doesn't keep it unicode, you can try replacing the tabs by pipes in the text file, using a macro like this one, found [here](http://vbabuff.blogspot.com/2010/03/mass-replace-characters-in-text-file.html). You can call it using

```
call TextFileReplace("C:\temp\test.txt","C:\temp\test2.txt",vbtab,"|")

Public Sub TextFileReplace(ByVal sFile As String, ByVal sNewFile As String, ByVal sFind As String, ByVal sReplace As String)
Dim iFile As Integer
Dim sTextBuffer As String
'
' Get the next available file handle
iFile = FreeFile
' Open the source file (sFile) for read access
Open sFile For Binary Access Read As iFile
' Create a buffer that will hold the contents of the file
sTextBuffer = Space(LOF(iFile))
' Read the contents of the file into the buffer
Get #iFile, , sTextBuffer
' Close the file
Close iFile

' Use the "Replace" function to replace all instances of
' (sFind) in the buffer with the value in (sReplace)
sTextBuffer = Replace(sTextBuffer, sFind, sReplace)

' Get the next available file handle
iFile = FreeFile
' Open/Create the new file for write access
Open sNewFile For Binary Access Write As iFile
' Write the modified buffer contents to the file
Put #iFile, , sTextBuffer
' Close the file
Close iFile
End Sub
```

Comment: I had already tried a similar macro.  Unfortunately, these don't save as Unicode, but UTF-8, removing the data from double byte characters.

Comment: OK, I've changed my answer to reflect that issue.

Comment: Ugh, now I get a run-time error: permission denied.  I get it at the line 'Open sNewFile For Binary Access Write As iFile'
and I can't really find a workaround

Comment: Is the txt file opened? That might be the issue. I ran that macro successfully on a closed txt file with excel 2010 on a windows 7 machine.

Comment: Indeed, the txt file is closed.

Comment: Do you have any access issues to the folder where the file is saved? Read, Write, etc.?

Comment: No, the file was on my desktop.

Answer (score 0):

I should also point out that search-n-replace will not properly fix quoted delimiters.